# Local node crash during solo mining

Tags: monerod, daemon, full-node, solo-mining

Monero lovers.

Recently I decided to mine Monero on my own and for this I installed a Full node with all blockchain. To install the node, I used a local computer with os: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS with an e5 2678 v3 processor and a 1 TB SSD. I have fast Internet and synchronization was successful in a day, the full node was ready with the daemon. In addition, I downloaded and installed GUI Wallet on the same computer, which started quite successfully and synchronized with the daemon. The block height matches.

After that, I installed xmrig-proxy for myself in order to be able to reduce the complexity of the ball for work machines, and on work machines I installed xmrig, where I registered the wallet obtained in my GUI Wallet and started mining.
However, such errors began to appear in the console.

```
2021-07-28 13:03:49.344 W ge_frombytes_vartime failed at 380
2021-07-28 13:03:49.354 E Exception at [core::handle_incoming_txs()], what=ge_frombytes_vartime failed at 380

2021-07-20 08:30:53.042 E Verification failure
```

Error in logs:

```
WARNING ringct  src/ringct/rctOps.cpp:415   ge_frombytes_vartime failed at 415
2021-07-17 01:50:02.712 [P2P8]  INFO    stacktrace  src/common/stack_trace.cpp:133  Exception: std::runtime_error
2021-07-17 01:50:02.712 [P2P8]  INFO    stacktrace  src/common/stack_trace.cpp:134  Unwound call stack:
2021-07-17 01:50:02.720 [P2P8]  INFO    stacktrace  src/common/stack_trace.cpp:172      [1]  0x113) [0x55ce2977aa4a]:__cxa_throw+0x113) [0x55ce2977aa4a]
2021-07-17 01:50:02.720 [P2P8]  INFO    stacktrace  src/common/stack_trace.cpp:172      [2] ./monerod(+0x353eb4) [0x55ce297b3eb4] 
2021-07-17 01:50:02.720 [P2P8]  INFO    stacktrace  src/common/stack_trace.cpp:172      [3]  0x2681) [0x55ce29df6221]:_ZN3rct18bulletproof_VERIFYERKSt6vectorIPKNS_11BulletproofESaIS3_EE+0x2681) [0x55ce29df6221]
2021-07-17 01:50:02.720 [P2P8]  INFO    stacktrace  src/common/stack_trace.cpp:172      [4]  0xd) [0x55ce29d6533d]:_ZN3rct14verBulletproofERKSt6vectorIPKNS_11BulletproofESaIS3_EE+0xd) [0x55ce29d6533d]
2021-07-17 01:50:02.720 [P2P8]  INFO    stacktrace  src/common/stack_trace.cpp:172      [5]  0xed4) [0x55ce29d79bb4]:_ZN3rct21verRctSemanticsSimpleERKSt6vectorIPKNS_6rctSigESaIS3_EE+0xed4) [0x55ce29d79bb4]
2021-07-17 01:50:02.720 [P2P8]  INFO    stacktrace  src/common/stack_trace.cpp:172      [6]  0x6a2) 


WARNING ringct  src/ringct/rctOps.cpp:380   ge_frombytes_vartime failed at 380
2021-07-28 13:03:49.345 [P2P0]  INFO    stacktrace  src/common/stack_trace.cpp:133  Exception: std::runtime_error
2021-07-28 13:03:49.345 [P2P0]  INFO    stacktrace  src/common/stack_trace.cpp:134  Unwound call stack:
2021-07-28 13:03:49.352 [P2P0]  INFO    stacktrace  src/common/stack_trace.cpp:172      [1]  0x113) [0x560e27da5a4a]:__cxa_throw+0x113) [0x560e27da5a4a]
2021-07-28 13:03:49.352 [P2P0]  INFO    stacktrace  src/common/stack_trace.cpp:172      [2] ./monerod(+0x353bca) [0x560e27ddebca] 
2021-07-28 13:03:49.352 [P2P0]  INFO    stacktrace  src/common/stack_trace.cpp:172      [3]  0x247) [0x560e28227997]:_ZNK10cryptonote4core32check_tx_inputs_keyimages_domainERKNS_11transactionE+0x247) [0x560e28227997]
2021-07-28 13:03:49.352 [P2P0]  INFO    stacktrace  src/common/stack_trace.cpp:172      [4]  0xd63) [0x560e2822c153]:_ZNK10cryptonote4core17check_tx_semanticERKNS_11transactionEb+0xd63) [0x560e2822c153]
2021-07-28 13:03:49.352 [P2P0]  INFO    stacktrace  src/common/stack_trace.cpp:172      [5]  0xbd) 

2021-07-20 08:30:53.042 [P2P8]  ERROR   bulletproofs    src/ringct/bulletproofs.cc:1075 Verification failure
2021-07-20 08:32:43.056 [P2P2]  INFO    stacktrace  src/common/stack_trace.cpp:133  Exception: boost::wrapexcept<boost::bad_weak_ptr>
2021-07-20 08:32:43.056 [P2P2]  INFO    stacktrace  src/common/stack_trace.cpp:134  Unwound call stack:
2021-07-20 08:32:43.061 [P2P2]  INFO    stacktrace  src/common/stack_trace.cpp:172      [1]  0x113) [0x55ce2977aa4a]:__cxa_throw+0x113) [0x55ce2977aa4a]
2021-07-20 08:32:43.061 [P2P2]  INFO    stacktrace  src/common/stack_trace.cpp:172      [2]  0x16c)
```

I don't understand why such errors occur, I downloaded all the files for installation from the official repository on github. My node is displayed in the list of open nodes, but these errors are very troubling to me.

Dear community, help me figure this out and understand what needs to be done so that such mistakes do not recur.

monero version: Oxygen Orion (v0.17.2.0-7d2e717ee)

First I wanted to write on github in the Monero repository, but I found out that I can't do it, it looks like the developers don't need bug reports, it's a pity.

Comment: "it looks like the developers don't need bug reports, it's a pity." <- there was a persistent spammer so issues had to be closed to the public. It's a pity, yes.

Comment: Spammers are a problem, I don’t argue. But I am not a spammer and I have never asked questions about Monero or any other mining product. I just want to understand what my problem is and ask the community to teach me how to solve such problems. I just want to mine Monero solo and nothing else.

Comment: github cannot tell in advance who will be a spammer, so you have to ask a member of the monero core team for access first. Either luigi1111 or fluffypony (on libera.chat IRC). Message them your email address and ask to be added to the github permissions list, then you will be able to flie a bug.

Comment: Thank you. I wrote to the users you mentioned on libera.chat IRC. Now I am waiting for an answer whether they will allow me to write or not